# Cannot get data using XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I am trying to get data from an XML file that's in the same directory as the HTML file, but no data seem to be returned (and I'm not sure how to render the data later). Here is the script (along with a sample record from the XML file I am trying to parse). Thanks for any help!

```
   function getFromAndDoThis(r, callback, opt="") {

    var okay = true;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (xhr) {  
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {callback(opt);}, false);
        xhr.open("GET", r, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    else {
        okay = false;
    }

    return okay;

}

/* callback function */

function displayCurriculum(which) {

    var data = null;
    var chapters, docroot;

    data = extractXMLData(xhr);

    if (data) {

        chapters = data.getElementsByTagName("Chapter");
        docroot = document.getElementsById("contentarea")[0];

        var i = 0;

        /* put each chapter and synopsis (if any) in nodes, and put these nodes in the DOM */       

        for (i=0; i < chapters.length; i++) {

            var chapter = chapters[i];
            var synopsis = chapter.firstChild;

            var div = document.createElement("div");

            var pc = document.createElement("p");
            var ps = document.createElement("p");

            div.setAttribute("id", toString(i));

            pc.innerHTML = chapter.innerHTML;
            ps.innerHTML = synopsis.innerHTML;

            /* nodes are filled. now attach them to the DOM */

            div.appendChild(pc);
            div.appendChild(ps);

            body.appendChild(div);

        } // end for

    } // end if
    else {
        alert("No data.");
    }

}
```

XML record:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Curriculum name="algebra">
    <Chapter>
        Numbers
        <Synopsis>
            Real numbers, the number line, arithmetic, factoring, decimals, exponents, radicals, and complex numbers.
        </Synopsis>
    </Chapter>
</Curriculum>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback function is trying to read `xhr`, but the variable is out of scope. You need to pass it to the callback function as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see you loading the XML.
You can do this via Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "yourxml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(displayCurriculum){
    }
});
```

Comment: The very first function in the code in the question loads the XML… and this question isn't tagged `jquery` so a jquery answer isn't appropriate.